# CSS: Blurred background except square

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a image background full width and height of the screen.

I want to blur it except a fixed square div in the center of the screen.
On button click I have a jquery script to make the fixed square div full height and width of the screen thus removing the blur.

So something like this tutorial:

https://codepen.io/ariona/pen/geFIK

Only then reverted. Is this possible?

```
<div class="img-square">
    <div class="img-square-wrapper">
        <div class="img-square-image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking about the following html line up to make this achievable.

EDIT: I didnt make myself clear, I want to make the following work:

https://jsfiddle.net/ox89m6zs/5/

When you click the body the box gets resized but I want it to become full width with the image on the same place.

Comment: You could try use an [svg that uses a blur effect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feGaussianBlur) and mask for the square

Comment: Your example uses an original image and a blurred version of the same image to achieve the effect. Just swabbing the urls should do the trick. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxMqXp

Comment: I think I did not made myself clear. I made a JS fiddle for you guys to see my problem. With the effect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something Like this ?

I used layered backgrounds to mimic the blur to some extent, but you only have to use the same background one is blurred and one is normal.

The key here is `background-attachment: fixed;` [Read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".img-square-image").draggable();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-square {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #464646fc, #383333ab), url('http://via.placeholder.com/300x300');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

.img-square-image {
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid lime;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/300x300');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-square">
  <div class="img-square-image"></div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

```js
document.querySelector(".img-square-image").onclick = (e) => {
  e.target.classList.add('expand');
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-square {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #464646fc, #383333ab), url('http://via.placeholder.com/300x300');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

.img-square-image {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/300x300');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.expand {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-square">
  <div class="img-square-image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didnt make myself clear, I changed my question with a fiddle.

Comment: @Senta Check The Edit, if it's what you wanted :)

Comment: Thank you! Your code helped me a lot! Got it working now, added the background-position: center to the image to make it responsive!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly, this is what you search for:

https://codepen.io/itamarshdev/pen/oyeGKV

```
$(function() {
    $( ".box" ).draggable();
});
```

@import "compass/css3";

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,400,700);

$normal-img:"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-3eBjuQpOGFw/U47yh_-OycI/AAAAAAAAI2U/uaU5pK49N1w/s1600/normal.jpg";
$blurred-img:"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-m8TxQMObg6c/U474EWu7Y9I/AAAAAAAAI2k/xkRGoIEC1iU/s1600/blur.jpg";

body{
    background-image:url($blurred-img);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    font-family:Raleway, Open Sans, Droid Sans, Roboto,arial, sans-serif;
}
.blurred-bg{
    background-image:url($normal-img);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.box{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
left:-webkit-calc( 50% - 250px );
top:20%;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:5px;
    @include box-shadow(0 20px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.6));
    border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    padding:20px;
    text-align: center;
    @include box-sizing(border-box);
    text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
display: flex;
transition: box-shadow .3s ease;

    &:active{
    cursor:move;
    @include box-shadow(0 20px 50px rgba(0,0,0,.9));
}

.content{
    margin: auto;
}
}
h1,h2,a,p{
    color:white;
    font-weight:100;

    .tinted &{
        color:black;
        text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    }
}
h2{ font-size: 14px }
p{ 
margin: 20px;
&.related{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #444;

    a{
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover{
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    }
}
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="box blurred-bg tinted">
<div class="content">
    <h1>Blurred Background</h1>
        <h2>By <a href="http://ariona.net" rel="follow" target="_blank">Ariona, Rian</a></h2>
        <p>Drag this box to move around</p>
    <p class="related">See also: <a href="https://codepen.io/ariona/details/LVZLGP/" target="_blank">Staged Dropdown Animation</a></p>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didnt make myself clear, I changed my question with a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what do you do, you can try to use background property in this mode:

```
background:url($blurred-img) 95% 50%;
```

Comment: I didnt make myself clear, I changed my question with a fiddle.